# ORACLE order by MONTH

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

How can I order by month in full name of the month?
And I want to get the results like this below:

```
FEBRUARY    0   80
MARCH       0   58
APRIL       0   39
```

This is my 1st simple script:

```
select to_char(month,'MONTH')month,mo_incoming,mt_outgoing 
from t_raw_settlement_tara_yearly 
order by month
```

output:

```
APRIL       0   39
FEBRUARY    0   80
MARCH       0   58
```

2nd Script is almost right but I want the month to be in full MONTH

```
select to_date(to_char(month,'MONTH'),'MONTH')month,mo_incoming,mt_outgoing 
from t_raw_settlement_tara_yearly 
order by month
```

output:

```
2/1/2015    0   80
3/1/2015    0   58
4/1/2015    0   39
```

Comment: they might own it. but oracle is not the same thing as mysql

Comment: Although the answer you chose gives a valid workaround, I have a strong feeling that your error occurs because you are using the same alias in the query as your field name. And the order by uses the alias rather than the field to order the rows. You should try your own query once, replacing the alias 'month' with something like 'month_name'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You alias `to_char(month,'MONTH')` to `month`. Now when you use `month` in `ORDER BY` it references the month string. Either use a different alias or qualify the column:

```
select to_char(month,'MONTH')month,mo_incoming,mt_outgoing 
from t_raw_settlement_tara_yearly t
order by t.month
```

Comment: I feel this answer is more accurate at resolving OP's problem.

Comment: Agree with @CodeNewbie -- month is a date.

Comment: @DavidAldridge It's interesting problem :) I can't delete my answer because it's marked as `solved`. I can't copy dnoeth's answer to my post because it's unfair. Do you know haw to solve it?

Comment: @dnoeth I appreciate your permission, but I can't because I want to be honest. I made mistake, my answer should be deleted. I wont to leave here only the best answer - your answer.

Comment: Hi @dnoeth, I think this is more accurate. Thanks by the way.

Comment: The best answer left :)